# How do i update just a rails variable through ajax correctly?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link to add documents to a user in a has_many :through relation and can't get my ajax to update the counter correctly. Either it won't update at all or everything updates to the same number. I am rendering @documents through the _document.html.erb partial from a different page.

## relations_controller.rb

```
def create
    current_user.read_documents << Document.find(params[:document_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
end
```

## _document.html.erb

```
<div class="parent">
    <%= link_to "Add", relations_path(document_id: document.id), method: :post, remote: "true", class: "add" %>
    <div class="counter"><%= documents.relations.count %></div>
</div>
```

## relations\create.js.erb

```
$('.add').bind('ajax:success', function() { 
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.counter').addClass('read-doc');
});
```

I'm pretty sure it worked a day ago, but I don't remember changing anything that could have affected it. I've tried passing an instance variable in @count, but it only works for the first element. Same if i pass the created object as an instance:

```
relations_controller.rb
@relation=Relation.create!(user: current_user, document: Document.find(params[:document_id])) 

create.js.erb
$(this).closest('.parent').find('.counter').addClass('read-doc').html('<%= @relation.document.relations.count %>');
```

When i click on the "Add" link for one doc it updates the counter correctly to a number n, but when I click on the link for any other doc, they all update to the same number n until i refresh the page. The debugger shows that the instance is being created correctly but not passed to the js.erb file. Is there any way to do this? Or maybe even a simpler way to just reload that one part of the view?

edit: If it is relevant console.logging the  $(this).closest('.parent').find('.counter').html() returns the number + 1 undefined for each following click, i.e. 0 undefineds on the first, 1 undefined on the second, 2 undefineds.. and so on.

Comment: What is the problem with update all the content?